# How do I restrict traffic from webapp to a subnet in VNet

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-virtual-network, vnet

I have 3 subnets in my VNet and I would like to restrict traffic coming from a VNET integration on a webapp to just one of the three subnets. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Inbound and outbound network traffic on a subnet can be [network security group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-nsg) controlled using a network security group. Controlling inbound traffic requires creating network security rules in a network security group, and then assigning the network security group the subnet containing the App Service Environment

Comment: Thanks for the response Vijisankar. How do I specify the Source in this case? The custom tags don't show up in the NSG(clssic) rules blade. The other option is to enter IP address. I'm not sure what IP address I am supposed to enter for inbound source. I am guessing that the IP address that's assigned to the web app via P2S VPN is dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

It totally possible by using NSG, please follow the recommendations from the service ASE
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/app-service-app-service-environment-control-inbound-traffic#creating-a-network-security-group

Comment: Did you ever find out if you can do this with regular webapps?